# JBoss Portal SSO replication in cluster using domain mode

Tags: jboss, jboss-portal

I am trying to set up SSO replication in domain mode for a customized JBoss Portal. I made the following changes in the domain.xml:

- To my server group which belongs to the ha-profile, I added:

  ```
  <system-properties> <property name="exo.profiles" value="cluster"/>
  <property name="gatein.jcr.config.type" value="cluster"/>
  <property name="gatein.jcr.index.changefilterclass" value="org.exoplatform.services.jcr.impl.core.query.jbosscache.LocalIndexChangesFilter"/>
  ```
- To the ha profile in domain.xml

  ```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
  <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
  <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
  <alias name="localhost"/>
  <alias name="example.com"/>
  <sso cache-container="web" cache-name="sso"/>
  </virtual-server>
  </subsystem>
  ```

I am having problems replicating the principal, I get a NPE when I try to obtain information from the user. This is a snippet of the logs.

```
########### log in @ server1 ########### 11:27:41,430 TRACE [org.jboss.as.web.sso] (ajp-/x.x.x.1:8009-4) Registering sso id 'qY0hc42eF1DFFXqtDHzJLse9' for user 'user@domain.com' with auth type 'FORM' 

11:27:41,432 TRACE [org.jboss.as.clustering.web.sso.infinispan.SSOClusterManager] (ajp-/x.x.x.1:8009-4) Registering SSO qY0hc42eF1DFFXqtDHzJLse9 in clustered cache   

########### shutdown @ server1 ########### 11:28:14,794 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBWEB003075: Coyote HTTP/1.1 pausing on: http-/x.x.x.1:8080  

########### sso update @ server2 ########### 

11:27:41,447 TRACE [org.jboss.as.clustering.web.sso.infinispan.SSOClusterManager] (OOB-18,shared=udp) received a credentials modified message for SSO qY0hc42eF1DFFXqtDHzJLse9 

11:27:41,462 TRACE [org.jboss.as.clustering.web.sso.infinispan.SSOClusterManager] (OOB-18,shared=udp) received a session modified message for SSO qY0hc42eF1DFFXqtDHzJLse9

11:28:15,577 TRACE [org.jboss.as.clustering.web.sso.infinispan.SSOClusterManager] (OOB-20,shared=udp) received a session modified message for SSO qY0hc42eF1DFFXqtDHzJLse9  

########### log in @ server2 ########### 11:28:15,578 TRACE [org.jboss.as.web.sso] (OOB-20,shared=udp) Notified that SSO qY0hc42eF1DFFXqtDHzJLse9 is empty 

11:28:35,530 TRACE [org.jboss.as.web.sso] (ajp-/x.x.x.2:8009-4) Checking for cached principal for qY0hc42eF1DFFXqtDHzJLse9 

11:28:35,532 TRACE [org.jboss.as.web.sso] (ajp-/x.x.x.2:8009-4) Found cached principal 'NULL' with auth type 'FORM'
```

The error when refreshing the page after fail over occurs:

```
11:28:44,054 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[customapp].[jsp]] (ajp-/x.x.x.2:8009-4) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.banners.customappbanner_jsp._jspService(customappbanner_jsp.java:148)
```

which is generated from the "else" part of this snippet:

```
<% if(request.getUserPrincipal() == null) {%>
                             <a href="/portal/login" id="sign-in" class="header-link" rel="nofollow">Login</a>
                             <% } else { %>
                             <ul class="header-link">
                                    <li class="hidden-xs"><i class="icons user"></i><%= request.getUserPrincipal().getName().toString() %></li>
```

Any hints would be greatly appreciated. 
Also, distributable tag is present in web.xml.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI, this is a SAML/SSO Valve problem for session replication. This is not supported by Portal/EAP at the moment.